# Using ConstraintLayout with Kotlin Anko

Tags: kotlin, anko, android-constraintlayout

I'm playing around with [ContraintLayout support in Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/ConstraintLayout) and running into an issue where I can't get the simplest possible example to work correctly.

I have two buttons laid out horizontally at the top of the screen in a constraintLayout, acting as a chain such that they are centered horizontally.

First thing I did was use good old xml layouts and Android Studio so I could take a look at the code produced.

Here's my non-Anko xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="First"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Second"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    />
```

This produces the correct layout as shown below

[image: what I expect]

Now below is what I believe should be the equivalent Kotlin Anko code to produce the same result.

```
constraintLayout {

                id = R.id.constraintRoot
                val first : Button = button("First"){
                    id = R.id.firstButton
                    width = wrapContent
                    height = wrapContent

                }.lparams{
                    //topToTop = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID
                    startToStart = PARENT_ID
                    endToStart = R.id.secondButton
                    horizontalChainStyle = spread
                    editorAbsoluteY = 16
                    horizontalBias = 0.5f
                }

                val second : Button = button("Second"){
                    id = R.id.secondButton
                    width = wrapContent
                    height = wrapContent
                }.lparams{
                    startToEnd = R.id.firstButton
                    endToEnd = PARENT_ID
                    editorAbsoluteY = 16
                    horizontalBias = 0.5f
                }
            }
```

But for some reason this produces the following result instead.

[image: wrong]

As you can see, the buttons aren't spread evenly and centered horizontally inside the view.

Is there anything I'm missing or is ConstraintLayout for Anko not quite ready for production use yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using a Guideline to give me the desired result.

```
constraintLayout {

                id = R.id.constraintRoot
                val first : Button = button("First"){
                    id = R.id.firstButton
                    width = wrapContent
                    height = wrapContent
                }.lparams{
                    endToStart = R.id.verticalGuideline
                    startToStart = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID
                }

                val gl : Guideline = guideline {
                    id = R.id.verticalGuideline
                }.lparams {
                    orientation = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.VERTICAL
                    guidePercent = 0.5f
                }

                val second : Button = button("Second"){
                    id = R.id.secondButton
                    width = wrapContent
                    height = wrapContent
                }.lparams{
                    startToEnd = R.id.verticalGuideline
                    endToEnd = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Width and height of the buttons should be lparams (either in the lparams body or as parameters to lparams(). I'm not sure if this will address the issue.